# Is it possible to do this Illustrator tutorial in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text

I am in the process of learning photoshop and came across this tutorial which create a great text effect, however it is written for illustrator. Does anybody know if there are any similar guides for doing this with photoshop? Or is it even possible?

http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/text-effects/how-to-make-a-wooden-text-effect-with-adobe-illustrator/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that effect possible to do in Photoshop? Yes.

However, you'll really need to make your own steps. There's nothing directly transferable from that tutorial to Photoshop. The tools are not similar at all.

Photoshop's 3D is much different than Illustrator's 3D. Gradients are adjusted differently. There's no pathfinder in Photoshop.

You would do best by simply looking at the step images they use and trying to mimic that set up in Photoshop. Reading the text of the tutorial won't be very helpful for anything but the texturizing and glows.